# how to clear cached only in IE7 through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I want to clear cache only for IE7, not in any other browser, how can i clear it.
i used following script to remove cache but it clear the cache of all browser, is there any solution to clear only the cache in IE7 through javascript?

```
<?phpheader("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");?>
```

Comment: why would you want to do that on ie7 only ? + we're talking of 1% of web users there

Comment: how can i add cachebusters?

Comment: bscause code is working perfectly fine in all other browser excet IE& and IE8, that's why i want to used it.

Comment: You should probably focus on solving the problem with IE7 & 8 rather than relying on forcing no-cache. But if you do want to do that, you will need to sniff the browser's User Agent and set the header accordingly. Not something that I'd recommend..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved to do this.

```
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

While what you are trying to do isn't a good idea, you could do it without javascript. You can use conditional comments and meta tags:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>

<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">

<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You are right but i want to do it with javascript or ajax. But thanks.